# Mapbox vector tile disappears at lower zoom levels

Tags: mapbox, vector-tiles, mapbox-gl

I am currently working with self-hosted vector tiles. These tiles are hosted on S3 and rendered on the map.
The zoom levels are from 0 to 10 and generally load on all levels since maxzoom has been added.
However, now the tiles do not load at lower zoom levels (below 6), but load at higher zoom levels.
This is the code being used

```
 map.addSource("<Source>", {
  "type": "vector",
  "tiles": [
    "<Tile-URL>{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"
  ],
  "maxzoom": 10,
  "minzoom": 0
 });


map.addLayer({
  "id": "<layer-id>",
  "type": "fill",
  "source": "<source-id>",
  "source-layer": "<source-layer>",
  "paint": {
      "fill-color": "#FF0000",
      "fill-opacity": 1,
      "fill-outline-color": "#FF0000"
  },
});
```

I cannot add the tile source as it is part of enterprise data. Does anyone know why this map won't load at lower zoom levels?

Comment: Any errors in the browser debugger console or network section?

Comment: Are you sure they are generated? Generating low-level tiles can be expensive, maybe they simply don't exist?

Comment: There's no errors in the console output @TomazicM

Comment: Is there a functionality for lower zoom levels (like maxZoom for higher zoom levels extrapolates on the existing tile) in Mapbox or leaflet? @Lukasz

Comment: What about errors in the browser debugger network section? What are the responses for for vector tile requests?